# 配列の要素数が未記述の場合の動作

Tags: c

以前、PPCGで以下の問題を回答しました。
[Make a “Ceeeeeeee” program](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100614/56344)

```
char x[];i;m(char*v,c){for(x[i]=*v;*v;)*++v-c?printf("%s%s\n",x,v):(x[++i]=c);}
```

実行結果:
`Make a "Ceeeeeeee" program`, `e`:

```
Make a "Ceeeeeeee" program
Mke a "Ceeeeeeee" program
Me a "Ceeeeeeee" program
Mea "Ceeeeeeee" program
Me "Ceeeeeeee" program
Me"Ceeeeeeee" program
MeCeeeeeeee" program
Meeeeeeeee" program
Meeeeeeeee program
Meeeeeeeeeprogram
Meeeeeeeeerogram
Meeeeeeeeeogram
Meeeeeeeeegram
Meeeeeeeeeram
Meeeeeeeeeam
Meeeeeeeeem
Meeeeeeeee
```

配列の要素数が無い(未記述)の場合でも、正しい結果を出せてしまうのか不思議です。
これは一体何故なのか、ご存知の方ご教授を宜しくお願いします。

Comment: コードや実行結果は質問にテキストで含めるようにして下さい。

Comment: 既に回答が付いてますが、警告も出てますね。＞「prog.c:1:6: warning: tentative array definition assumed to have one element」

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ファイルスコープ（つまり大域変数として）で
`char x[];`
のようにした場合、暗黙的に（要素が１つあるとする）
`char x[1];`
だと見なされます。
それで、`x[0]`に対する読み書きはＯＫです。
しかし、`x[10]`など要素数以上の要素に書いたり読み出したりした結果は動作未定義です。
正常に動作するように見えるかもしれませんし、正常に動作しないかもしれないし、セグメントフォールトを起こすかもしれません。

Ｃコンパイラは配列へのアクセスの範囲チェックは基本行わないので、コンパイルはできてしまいます。

Comment: `char x[];` が `char x[1];` と見なされる、というのは言語仕様書に明記されていないような気がします。オイラの見落としかもしれないので JIS X 3010 なり ISO/IEC 9899 のどこにそういう文言があるか教えていただけると幸いです。ちなみに  Visual C++ 2008 や Renesas SH C/C++ は挙動が違いました。 gcc 固有な動作なような気がしなくもない・・・

Comment: @774RR  要素を１つ持つとみなすということでもちろん`char x[1];`と同じではありません。

Comment: g++ だと `storage size of x isn't known` コンパイルエラーとなりました。 Visual C++ 2008 (の C コンパイラ) では `extern char x[];` 扱いとなりました。 SH C Compiler だと `C2127 Missing array size` となりました。 RX C Compiler だと `char x[1];` 扱いでした。ご報告まで。

Comment: @774RR  6.9.2 External object definitions(n1570.pdfを参照してます）を読んでみて下さい。パラグラフ５にそのものずばりの例があります。

Comment: なるほど了解です。 JIS X 3010:2003 から引用しておきます。翻訳単位が  `int i[];` を含み <snip> 配列 `i` は暗黙の初期化子によって１つの要素をもつようにされる。その要素には 0 がセットされる。 C の難解な仮定義が C++ ではなくなっていますし C++ のほうが幸せになれそうです。